android - hilt - How can change retrofit creation after the initialization?
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    /*
    @Singleton
           TR -> Tüm uygulamada oluşturulan tek örnek kullanılacak bir daha instance oluşturmayacak ---silinebilir
           EN -> The only instance created in the entire application will be used and will not create another instance ---can be deleted
     */

    private var retrofitInstance: Retrofit? = null

    private fun createRetrofitInstance(): Retrofit{
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .apply {
                if (**Utils.isDeveloper**) { // Chuck On/Off Preference
                    addInterceptor(ChuckInterceptor(Utils.context))
                }
            }
            .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(WebServiceUtils.generateBaseUrl())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }`

    fun updateRetrofitInstance() {
        retrofitInstance = createRetrofitInstance()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitInstance(): Retrofit {
        if (retrofitInstance == null) {
            retrofitInstance = createRetrofitInstance()
        }
        return retrofitInstance!!
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideTransactionService(retrofit: Retrofit): TransferRestInterface{
        return retrofit.create(TransferRestInterface::class.java)
    }
}

How can I ensure the use of the up-to-date Retrofit object?
apply {
if (Utils.isDeveloper) { // Chuck On/Off Preference
addInterceptor(ChuckInterceptor(Utils.context))
}
}

In this part, I retrieve the value of isDeveloper with SharedPreferences. When the application runs, Retrofit is created directly and retrieves the value of isDeveloper. Later, even though the Retrofit object is updated when changing the isDeveloper value in the settings screen, the program still uses the previous one.
The reason for this is that when the program first opens, the following part works:
@Provides
fun provideTransactionService(retrofit: Retrofit): TransferRestInterface{
    return retrofit.create(TransferRestInterface::class.java)
}

Afterward, even if Retrofit is updated, this part no longer works.

The only thing you should really need to have as a singleton with retrofit is the okhttp instance. The actual retrofit instance does not need to be especially if you need to change it
